# reading column header in excel file

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am reading data from excel file using OLEDB connection. But the problem is I can't read the column header.
I am using

```
String sConnectionString1 = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" +"E:\\"+
                             Sourcefilename + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;Format=xls;'";
```

in connection string..
please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Load the Excel in Dataset and Access the Column collection to get the ColumnName gives the Column header

```
       foreach (DataColumn dc in output.Tables[0].Columns)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(dc.ColumnName);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `GetSchemaTable` on the `SqlDataReader` derived class returns a `DataTable` with a [`Columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columns.aspx) property. This will give you the names of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OLEDB to connect and read from excel sheets. Here is a good example http://codehill.com/2009/01/reading-excel-2003-and-2007-files-using-oledb/