# how to get first row and column value from data table which contain value from excel sheet using c# to create dynamic table in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I had exported data from excel file to data table.what I want to take header of excel file and make a dynamic table in SQL database every time I update a new excel
here is my code to import data from excel to the data table.

```
  protected DataTable DataExcel()
    {

        DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        try
        {
            string filenname=@"C:\Users\sani singh\Documents\Excel03.xls";
            string sWorkbook = "[Sheet1$]";
            string ExcelConnectionString=@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+filenname+";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
            OleDbConnection OleDbConn = new OleDbConnection(ExcelConnectionString);
            OleDbConn.Open();
            OleDbCommand OleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand(("SELECT * FROM " + sWorkbook), OleDbConn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(OleDbCmd);
            sda.Fill(ds);
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            OleDbConn.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Create a dynamic CREATE TABLE string. EXECUTE it over your SQL connection. Hopefully, you have table headers available in the datatable. Loop through them to create the query. Table can be named like tbl_ddmmyy_hhmmss. Your sql user to execute the query should have CREATE permission in db. Once the table is created, and you have the table name, you can insert the data or SQL BULK COPY (ADO.NET) it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227306/converting-a-data-table-to-an-create-table-insert-script-for-sql-in-c-sharp

Comment: see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856440/reading-column-header-in-excel-file